# Add SCR feature in karaf 2.3.10

Tags: java, apache-karaf

I've installed Apache Karaf 2.3.10 in my environment to deploy OSGi bundles. I need to add SCR feature to karaf. I tried by following the steps in this [link](http://sully6768.blogspot.in/2012/09/scr-components-with-karaf-part-1.html). It won't show the installed components as similar to `osgi:install` command. Can anybody tell me any references or steps to add the SCR feature?

Comment: Have you added scr features using : features:addurl mvn:org.apache.karaf.scr/org.apache.karaf.scr.feature/2.2.9/xml/features and install the scr feature like : features:install scr

Comment: please tell me for 2.3.10. i hope its for 2.2.9

Comment: even i tired that one too. no use

Comment: After doing features:list | grep scr what you have seen? If the scr features added then do install -s mvn:org.apache.karaf.scr/org.apache.karaf.scr.examples.service/2.2.9

Comment: Please tell me for 2.3.10 not for 2.2.9. I tried by changing the version in the above url. It didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You can install it with `features` command as follows:

```
karaf@root> features:install scr
```

I have just tested with 2.3.10 and it works fine. No need to add extra repositories to features repos